# Insertar una etiqueta a todas las etiquetas que tengan una clase en especifico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero insertar una etiqueta ***li*** dentro de todos los ***ul*** que tengan la clase o id ***'padre'***. Y que termine algo asi:

```
<ul id='padre'>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
</ul>

<ul id='padre'>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
</ul>

<ul id='padre'>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
  <li id='hijo'></li>
</ul>
```

El codigo que estoy utilizando es este

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#padre').after('<li>NIVEL 3</li>');
});
```

Pero solo le agrega ese **li** al primer **ul** que tiene el id **'padre'**

Comment: Hola Lila. Y qué has intentado o qué has investigado? qué problemas concretos has tenido? Nosotros ayudamos a resolver tus errores, no tareas.Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Pulsa en [edit] para explicar mejor el antes y el despues de tu programa.  Un saludo

Comment: Con Jquery es sencillisimo. Echale un vistazo.

Comment: Dale, ahora lo edito

Comment: ten en cuenta que el id está pensado para ser unico. por eso solo te añadirá detras del primero que encuetnre con ese id.

Comment: bueno ya hay una respuesta solo quería hacer una observación por si acaso. nunca repitas los ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa JQuery, es sencillo usando el `append`, puedes usar una clase `padre` para que funcione en todos:

```js
 
$(".padre").append("<li>Test hijo</li>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='padre'>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
</ul>

<ul class='padre'>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
</ul>

<ul class='padre'>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
  <li id='hijo'>1</li>
</ul>
```

La función del `append` consiste en insertar el contenido especificado al final de cada elemento en el conjunto de elementos coincidentes (en este caso a aquellos que contengan la clase `class='padre'`).

Puedes acceder a la siguiente ruta: http://api.jquery.com/append/ , te explica más a detalle en lo que consiste el `append`.
Espero te ayude.

Comment: estaría bueno explicar que hace `$(Selector).append()` y dejar una referencia a la documentación. Saludos!

Comment: Listo @FranIslas, tienes razón, es bueno dejar referencia para que ayude a comprender lo que se hizo. Saludos.